# How to pin Internet Explorer to taskbar with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am setting a script to pin internet explorer to task-bar for all users using Power Shell. the code i have run only is successfully for pinning notepad but i want it to work for internet explorer. Any one who can help me on this?

```
$sa = new-object -com shell.application
$pn = $sa.namespace($env:windir).parsename('iexplorer.exe')
$pn.invokeverb('taskbarpin')
```

I have tried putting `parsename('notepad.exe')` and it ran,But i want to put internet explorer like this `parsename('iexplorer.exe')`.

When i run the code the console says `powershell: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Answer (score 0):

if you check what `$pn.items()` returns, you can see there is no internet explorer.
You need to use the installation path of the internet explorer as an namespace.

Try it like that:
`$sa.namespace("C:\Program Files\internet explorer").parsename('iexplore.exe')`

Note:

Transfered comment to answer